# submitting a form,it shows, "column_name cannot be null", but inside the form the value is not null. (Codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter

View: (inside view, transaction_particular_name is not null)

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url().'user/add_transaction'; ?>">
  <div class="container">
  <label for="uname"><b>Purpose of Fee's</b></label>
    <select name="transaction_particular_name">
      <?php foreach($all_particular as $key){ ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $key->particular_name; ?>"><?php echo $key->particular_name; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>       
    <button type="submit">Proceed</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Controller(User): (just calling the model)

```
public function add_transaction()
      {
        $query=$this->Mdl_data->insert_transaction();
      }
```

Model(Mdl_data):(inside model, the property is null)

```
public function insert_transaction()
    {

        $tablename='transaction';
        $columns_and_fields = array('transaction_particular_name');
          foreach ($columns_and_fields as $key) 
            $data[$key]=$this->input->post($key);
        $query=$this->db->insert($tablename,$data);
        return $query;
    }
```

Please help anyone, I want to get rid of it.

Comment: You are trying to get `transaction_particular_name` from loop?

Comment: First, try to learn how MVC works. You are getting data in the model.

Comment: Yes. When I try to get another value like:
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Transaction ID" name="transaction_id" required>

Comment: getting single value or multiple?

Comment: When I try to get data without loop, it shows the same database error.
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Transaction ID" name="transaction_id" required>

Comment: what is the database error?

Comment: I want to insert multiple data inside a form to database.

Comment: A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1048

Column 'transaction_particular_name' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `transaction` (`transaction_particular_name`) VALUES (NULL)

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/southern/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Answer (score 0):

You have too many error at your code... try this.. and it will only add you field .. without any error...
at controller

```
    // $data = $this->input->post('transaction_particular_name');
$data = $_POST['transaction_particular_name'];
if($data){
  $query=$this->Mdl_data->insert_transaction($data);
} else {
    echo "unable to capture data... "
}
```

and at model

```
public function insert_transaction($data = '')
    {

        $tablename='transaction';
        $columns_and_fields = array('transaction_particular_name'=>$data); 
        $this->db->insert($tablename,$columns_and_fields);
    }
```

Comment: Error still exists, sir.

Comment: A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1048

Column 'transaction_particular_name' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `transaction` (`transaction_particular_name`) VALUES (NULL)

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/southern/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: Sorry sir. It echoes, "unable to capture data..."

Comment: Try the edited one.. seems like you haven load form library at autoload... if it wont work ... check the documentation .. and autoload form library..

Answer (score 0):

First, learn how **Model-View-Controller** works

Second, `<select name="transaction_particular_name">` is inside loop

Try to get like this

```
<select name="transaction_particular_name[]">
```

Your data will get in Controller, not in Model

**Controller**

`$transaction_particular_name` will get in an array form use `foreach` loop to insert

```
public function add_transaction()
{
    foreach($transaction_particular_name as $trans){
        $data = array('transaction_particular_name' => $trans);
        $query=$this->Mdl_data->insert_transaction($data);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public function insert_transaction($data)
{
   return $this->db->insert('transaction', $data);
}
```

Comment: I have written according to what you said. Its still giving me the error, A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1048

Column 'transaction_particular_name' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `transaction` (`transaction_particular_name`) VALUES (NULL)

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/southern/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: Check what is the result of  `print_r($this->input->post()); die();` In the controller function